# How to resolve "A Database Error Occurred" using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am a student that is trying to get a past project working on my HP laptop.

Previously (over a year ago), I had managed to set up this website on a local server using XAMPP, but reading around I assume that the database is outdated and is providing me the below error:

**A Database Error Occurred**

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/media.einnovention.com/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 436

The database has the below comments.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.5
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Jul 17, 2019 at 11:04 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.44
-- PHP Version: 7.2.7
```

I am using XAMPP version 3.2.4 which comes with mySQL version 5.6.20.

I have come across the following link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html

But, being the newbie I am I cannot comprehend what needs to be done to edit and adjust the database.

*note that I was able to successfully import the database to PHPmyadmin, but still the website will not load on my localhost and provides me with the error in the description above.*

*Edit*

Below is code from the DB_Driver.php file.

```
/**
 * Data Source Name / Connect string
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $dsn;

/**
 * Username
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $username;

/**
 * Password
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $password;

/**
 * Hostname
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $hostname;

/**
 * Database name
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $database;

/**
 * Database driver
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $dbdriver        = 'mysqli';

/**
 * Sub-driver
 *
 * @used-by CI_DB_pdo_driver
 * @var string
 */
public $subdriver;

/**
 * Table prefix
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $dbprefix        = '';

/**
 * Character set
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $char_set        = 'utf8';

/**
 * Collation
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $dbcollat        = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Please share some code examples. It can be the content of `DB_driver.php`. Did you check if your PHP MySQL connector uses the right configurations, i.e. host, port, user, and password?

Comment: @metad00r I have proceeded to add code from the DB_Driver.php file. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Is that the complete DB_driver.php file? The error message indicates a link 436 but the file is less the 100 lines. Anyway, the error message seems to indicate that your database isn't running, you're using the wrong username/password, or some other variation of "trouble connecting to the database". Try connecting from the command line client or looking in your process list to make sure the database is running. At this stage, it doesn't seem to be a corrupted table or problem with the .sql file.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch thanks. I updated the database.php files to be same username as phpmyadmin and it no longer provides me the error